# HDFS directory count

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a bunch of directories in HDFS as:

```
stuff A: /stuff/prod/data/inputData
stuff B: /stuff/prod/data/global/holdingpen
stuff C: /stuff/prod/data/global/keepers
stuff D: /stuff/prod/data/global/actionDFiles
stuff E: /stuff/prod/data/global/expired
stuff H: /stuff/prod/data/global/actionHFiles
stuff L: /stuff/prod/data/global/billableSessionTopXRecompute
stuff R: /stuff/prod/data/global/billingIdTimeRecompute
stuff U: /stuff/prod/data/global/uniqueStats
stuff Z: /stuff/prod/data/global/cleanupOldVersions
```

and currently I just run something like this for each directory to get a count

```
hadoop fs -ls /stuff/prod/data/global/actionHFiles | wc -l
20658
```

I'd like to be able to do this in a bash script that would simply print out like so

```
Stuff A: 183729
Stuff B: 281948
```

etc.  Can anyone help?  Thanks

Comment: what about hdfs dfs -count /stuff/prod/data/global/* ?

Comment: that works thanks...   I also found if I wan to actually see the size I can do something like this: hadoop fs -du -s -h /stuff/prod/data/global/ActionHFiles